# How to change ldap request to relational database?

Tags: c#, java, database, ldap

I want to do this: some one sends a request by LDAP protocal, for example, username and password, to authenticate.

Is there any ways(program with c#、java or else) to interface from this LDAP protocol to a relational database (and not the standard LDAP storage), get the results from that database and return the result by LDAP protocol?

Comment: might want to take a look @ http://www.openldap.org/

Comment: So you want to replace the LDAP backend with a relational database? Why not eliminate the LDAP infrastructure completely and replace it with a simple jdbc/odbc backend, because that's about the same amount of effort

Comment: @Petesh, Because some softwares must use LDAP to authenticate, but I am familiar with the database, I want to set something betweent the software and database and it can help software and database to communicate with LDAP protocal.

Comment: If the directory server in use provides pass-through authentication, BIND requests can be directed to another server. Some LDAP directory servers support the notion of a pass-through plugin which can be custom-coded if required.

Comment: I cannot understand the closure of this question. It is perfectly reasonable, comprehensible, and has a correct answer as given by @Anton. Voting to re-open. Not understanding the question is not itself evidence that the question is meaningless. You need more.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, and I hope that someone can provide a hint or an example on how to accomplish that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are various [backends](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/backends.html) for openldap. If none of the direct database backends work for you, you can always consider using the Perl interface to get the data to/from the relational database with appropriate mappings.

Comment: Exactly. The SQL backend does exactly what the OP requires.

Answer (score -1):

Intercepting and parsing the ldap query data might be a huge overhead for your needs. I believe that the most efficient way around your problem would be to write a simple application / script in your preferred programming language that pulls your user accounts from your relational database at regular intervals ( or is triggered when data changes in your DB ) and creates them on ldap server. That way, you can use the DB as "master", but ldap would be used to authenticate.

This solution requires, however, that you can either access the users' passwords in an unencrypted manner or that the encryption / hashing mechanism is compatible with ldap.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. He didn't say anything about intercepting and parsing, nor anything about an offline conversion.

Comment: I might have interpreted the question a bit differently, the core idea stays, however. To achieve the desired goal, the best shot at this would be to transfer the data from the relational database into the ldap database everytime the master data changes ( or at regular intervals ). Then use ldap to provide the data to the requestor.

Comment: *Why* is that the 'best shot'? Why isn't have a single database a better solution? You can't just make blanket statements like this without providing any reasons.